# seit or seitdem? Which one is correct?

Tags: conjunction

Why should I use *seit* and not *seitdem* in these sentences?

> **Seit** ich mehr Gehalt bekomme, muss ich auch mehr Steuern bezahlen.
>
> **Seit** ich ein neues Auto habe, macht mir das Fahren wieder mehr Spaß.
>
> **Seit** wir uns ein Auto mit den Nachbarn teilen, sparen wir viel Geld.

Answer (score 6):

> Why should I use seit and not seitdem in these sentences?

It's [grammatically perfectly fine](https://deutschegrammatik20.de/komplexer-satz/satzverbindung-temporal-seitdem-seit/) to use seit or seitdem in your examples. But, [some people](https://bastiansick.de/kolumnen/abc/seitseitdem/) say its stylistically unattractive, because seitdem should refer to something you have said, not something you are going to say.

They say you should write

> Seit ich mehr Gehalt bekomme, muss ich auch mehr Steuern bezahlen.
>
> Ich bekomme mehr Gehalt. Seitdem muss ich auch mehr Steuern bezahlen.

But from my point of view ... it's "gehopst wie gesprungen" (it's the same).

Comment: Sick is so head-clutchingly dumb. According to his logic, *nachdem* should mean *danach*. But thank you for pointing out the source of this befuddling rule.

Answer (score 4):

They can both be used in the sentences given.

> **Seitdem** ich mehr Gehalt bekomme, muss ich auch mehr Steuern bezahlen.
>
> **Seitdem** ich ein neues Auto habe, macht mir das Fahren wieder mehr Spaß.
>
> **Seitdem** wir uns ein Auto mit den Nachbarn teilen, sparen wir viel Geld.

Is correct but you should use Seit.

Seitdem should be used when referencing a previously mention action or event.

As an exemple:

> Ich bekomme mehr Gehalt, **seitdem** muss ich mehr Steuern bezahlen.

Comment: Why recommend using *seit* instead of *seitdem* when both are perfectly possible?

Comment: Because Seitdem is use for the special case I gave an example for. You may use seitdem in cases where you use seit but not seit in cases where you use Seitdem.
"Ich bekomme mehr Gehalt, seit muss ich mehr Steuern bezahlen." Would be wrong.